# Java: Error reading text file to array

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read a text file to an arrayList but it's telling me

> "no suitable method found for add(string) method
>   Collection.add(Animal) is not applicable (argument mismatch; String
>   cannot be converted to Animal)"

I have a class called Animal and within that this is my constructor code

```
    //Constructor
public Animal(String aType, String aColor, boolean aVertebrate, boolean aFly, boolean aSwim) {
    type = aType;
    color = aColor;
    vertebrate = aVertebrate;
    fly = aFly;
    swim = aSwim;

}
```

In my main class this is the code I'm using to read the text file

```
    else if (menuSelection.equalsIgnoreCase("I")){
            Animal a;
            String line;

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("animalFile.txt"))){
                if (!br.ready()){
                    throw new IOException();
                }
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                    animalList.add(line);
                }
                br.close();
            }catch (FileNotFoundException f){
                System.out.println("Could not find file");
            }catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Could not process file");
            }

            int size = animalList.size();
             for (int i = 0; i < animalList.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(animalList.get(i).toString());
             }
```

I'm getting the error message on the "animalList.add(line)"

Comment: which kind of error? post the exact error message please.

Comment: No suitable method found for add(String) method Collection.add(Animal) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Animal)
method List.add(Animal) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Animal)
method AbstractCollection.add(Animal) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Animal)
method AbstractList.add(Animal) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Animal)
method ArrayList.add(Animal) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Animal)

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize if I pressed Enter that it would post the comment instead of going to the next line. I edited the post so you can see the full message.

Comment: The answer by @Eduardo will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list `animaList` is a list of `Animal`. [BufferedReader readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) returns `String`, therefore you cannot add a `String` to a list of `Animal`.

In this line you should a call a method that converts the string to an animal object.

```
 while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     Animal animal = getAnimal(line);
     animalList.add(animal);
 }
```

The method would like:

```
private Animal getAnimal(String in) {

// Split string and initialize animal object correctly

}
```

Comment: I've never used split before so I'm not sure if this is right, I did String s1; s1=animalList.add(new Animal(a.getType(),a.getColor(),String.valueOf(a.isVertebrat‌​e()),String.valueOf(‌​a.canFly()), String.valueOf(a.canSwim())); But its saying "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean" I thought I fixed that by doing String.valueof ?

Comment: what is a? 

can you provide an example line you would get?

Comment: a is a reference to the Animal class, I have it as Animal a;

Comment: can you provide a sample line so I can give you some sample code.

Comment: I have a text file that reads dog+red+true+true+true, I would like when the user chooses to import that text file that the console would read 

dog
red
true
true
true

Comment: sorry the formatting doesn't work on the comments or at least I don't know how to but image that the reading part would be dog above red, red above true and so on

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown what `animalList` is, but from the code , I deduce it is a `List` of `Animal`. `br.readLine()` returns `String` , but you are adding it to `animalList` which expects `Animal`. Hence, the error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "animalList" intended to be a list of objects of Animal type. So when you invoke animalList.add(line) this tries to add a String object (since `line = br.readLine()` reads a string from a file) whilest `Animal` object is expected to be added.

What you need to do in particular is

1. parse a string into a pieces of data which accepts your Animal contructor (aType, aColor, etc..)
2. Amend `animalList.add(line)` to `animalList.add(new Animal(/*Put parsed parameters here*/))`..

Comment: I've never used split before so I'm not sure if this is right, I did String s1;
s1=animalList.add(new Animal(a.getType(),a.getColor(),String.valueOf(a.isVertebrate()),String.valueOf(a.canFly()), String.valueOf(a.canSwim()));

But its saying "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean" 

I thought I fixed that by doing String.valueof ?

Comment: @BrookeTaylor valueOf only returns a String representation of a primitive type. If your line represents some parameters of an animal you need to split the strings and then convert splitted partes to the types which are accepted by your constructor. You can convert string to boolean using the following code: Boolean.getBoolean(yourStringValueRepresentingTrueOrFalse)

Comment: It's user input so there isn't a set string value since it can change. Would it just be Boolean.getBoolean(a.isVertebrate())?

Comment: @BrookeTaylor sorry I do not get it. I thought your code takes string from file and populates the list of Animals from that file. So what do you mean when you say that "it is user input"?

Comment: Well the user first does user input and then exports it to a text file, then the user can choose to import that text file and put those strings into an array to populate the list of animals.

Comment: @BrookeTaylor so the exporting user input to a file is not a subject of your question. Hence you will unlikely get any advice on this part. I suggest to decompose your task and concentrate on reading objects from file. Prepare a text file as it is supposed to be after the export and master the code you're asking the help for in this particular question.

Comment: I got it to work thanks to most of everyone's suggestions. Thank you so much sorry for any confusion.